# create a list (or any variable) dynamically, add data to each list and later compare them in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a `list` of some strings and I want to create a list for each of them dynamically inside a loop.

The main idea is to get each string from this `list` through the loop and create a list with this string as a name. Then add some data to it.

Example:

```
   List<string> names = new List<string>(); // this is the main list with strings

   foreach (string nm in name)
   {
     // Here create a new list with this name
     // Add data to the list
   }  

   // Now, compare all of them to find duplicate data

   // Give message if any duplicate data found
```

Update:
Basically, I am going to add data to the `list` using some database APIs on runtime and the string names are the keys in that API. So with each name in the main list, I will retrieve some data from the database, create a list with that name and add data to it. Later we will compare them together. So the basic question is still how do I create these `list`s at runtime.

Comment: Seems to be an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)

Comment: I guess the objective of you question is you want to know weather a list contains duplicate records or not?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan: Perfect, right this is what exactly I want to do. I will update the description now for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Use a generic Dictionary:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>(); // this is the main list with strings
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach (string name in names)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(name))
        dict.Add(name, new List<string>());
    dict[name].Add("another one bytes the dust :)");
}
```

In the above example, you will have a Dictionary with amount of keys equals to the number of unique names, and you can find duplicates by keys having more than one item in their associated List.

For example:

```
string[] dupes = dict.Keys.ToList().Find(k => dict[k].Count > 1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq to Object to determine that the list has duplicate records or not

```
bool IsDuplicate  = (names.Count != names.Distinct().Count());

if(IsDuplicate) {
    // Message : List has duplicate values.
}
```

Good Luck

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear at the beginning, I wanted to create the `list`s at runtime and compare them.

Comment: @Chetan, no problem with that, the "names" is the collection variable which i used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IList<KeyValuePair<String,IList<SomethingData>>>` or `Hastable<String,IList<SomethingData>>`

```
 //fill data to lists
 IList<KeyValuePair<String,IList<SomethingData>>> dataSets=new  List<KeyValuePair<String,IList<SomethingData>>>();
 IList<string> names = new List<String>();
 foreach (string nm in names)
 {
     IList<SomethingData> data = new List<SomethingData>();
     //...fill data
     dataSets.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, IList<SomethingData>>(nm, data));
 } 

 //search lists by name
 String nameForSearch = "test";
 IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String,IList<SomethingData>>> dataSetsByName = dataSets.Where(ds => ds.Key == nameForSearch);
```